# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for NSManagedObject implementing a protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, protocols, exc-bad-access

I have the following two methods:

```
func isAuthenticated() -> Bool {
    var currentUser: CurrentUser? = self.getCurrentUser()

    if currentUser == nil {
        return false
    }

    self.token = getUserToken(currentUser!.username)
    if self.token == nil {
        return false
    }

    if !tokenIsValidForUser(self.token!, user: currentUser!) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func tokenIsValidForUser(token: AuthenticationToken, user: UserObject) -> Bool {
    if token.username != user.username {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

When I call `isAuthenticated()`, it fails on the first line of `tokenIsValidForUser()` with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, apparently on the CurrentUser object.

My understanding si that you get this kind of error when the object no longer exists, but I cannot understand why this would be the case.

The object type CurrentUser is declared as:

```
protocol UserObject {
    var username: String { get set }
}

class CurrentUser: NSManagedObject, UserObject {

    @NSManaged var username: String

}
```

Comment: Before you call the method "tokenIsValidForUser", print the token and currentUser properties. I suspect that one of them is nil.

Comment: @JoJoe Neither of them is nil. However, what is interesting is if I `println` on either object, e.g. `println(currentUser!)` I get a blank line. If I `println(currentUser!.username)` it will print out the value for username.

Comment: Well, I can't find anything wrong with your code... Maybe someone else.

Comment: This issue is definitely to do with currentUser... and now I'm thinking it may be related to it being an NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue here:

http://lesstroud.com/dynamic-dispatch-with-nsmanaged-in-swift/

Essentially, this is a quirk of Swift when implementing protocols on Objects that are NSManaged. I had to add the `dynamic` keyword to my @NSManaged properties in the CurrentUser class, so that the class looked like this:

```
class CurrentUser: NSManagedObject, UserObject {

    @NSManaged dynamic var username: String

}
```

Comment: Any idea why the f*** this is?

Comment: Managed object properties were usually dynamically managed in obj-c as well. Remember using dynamic instead of synthesize?