# Swift linker error for NSManagedObject subclass implementing a protocol with a required init

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, alamofire

I'm having issues in a Swift project that I started. I'm using Alamofire for networking and MagicalRecord as a wrapper for Core Data. I don't know if that matters, but I'm mentioning it anyway.

## Setup

The application is retrieving its data from a JSON API. Using [Alamofire's Generic Response Object Serialization](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization) I created an extension of `Alamofire.Request` as can be seen at the linked page and implemented the following protocol:

```
@objc public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}
```

The class I created looked like this:

```
final class Foo: ResponseObjectSerializable {
    let bar: String
    let baz: String

    required init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        self.bar = representation.valueForKeyPath("bar") as String
        self.baz = representation.valueForKeyPath("baz") as String
    }
}
```

To retrieve the JSON data and serialize it as `Foo` all I had to do was the following:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://foo.com/api").responseObject { (_, _, foo: Foo?, _) in
    println(foo.bar)
}
```

So far, so good.

## The problem: adding Core Data

The problem started when I wanted to add Core Data functionality. I want to use the above approach to retrieve the data from the API, serialize it and at some point save it using Core Data.

So, I decided to adjust the above `Foo` class into this:

```
@objc(Foo)
final class Foo: NSManagedObject, ResponseObjectSerializable {
    @NSManaged var bar: String
    @NSManaged var baz: String

    required init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        self.bar = representation.valueForKeyPath("bar") as String
        self.baz = representation.valueForKeyPath("baz") as String
    }
}
```

That didn't work, since a `NSManagedObject` subclass needs a designated initializer, so I changed my class into:

```
@objc(Foo)
final class Foo: NSManagedObject, ResponseObjectSerializable {
    @NSManaged var bar: String
    @NSManaged var baz: String

    convenience required init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext.defaultContext()
        let entity  = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Foo", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        self.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        self.bar = representation.valueForKeyPath("bar") as String
        self.baz = representation.valueForKeyPath("baz") as String
    }
}
```

## Error

The project does compile, which seemed promising, but raises the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "__TFC7Project3Foo3barSS", referenced from:
>
> **TFC7Project3FoocfMS0_FT8responseCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse14representationPSs9AnyObject__GSqS0** in Foo.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea why it's causing that error and I would really love to get rid of it. So, does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

### Why am I using this approach?

I have a search functionality in my iOS app (in a modal). The search results are listed as `Foo` instances, but I'm not saving any of them locally (yet). This approach is just a convenient way to list the retrieved JSON data easily in a UITableView.

Once a search result is selected (from that list), I want to add that specific item to a local database using Core Data. Only those saved items will be listed in the main view of the app. Using the same class for that seems convenient in my opinion.

### What I've tried (apart from the above)

Before creating this question I tried to google for some solutions (but could find any workable answers) and used the search function on this site. I've found a couple of (somewhat) related questions:

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574105) I had to use Xcode 6.3 beta, which I've tried `(6D543q)`, but that didn't work either. I'm currently using `Xcode 6.2 (6C131e)` btw.

Another question which seemed related had the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25801997/4687420). So, I added `dynamic` to the variable declaration: `@NSManaged dynamic var bar: String`, but that didn't work either.

### Notes

I would also like to note that I'm new to iOS (and Swift), so I might not be using the correct (or should I say recommended) approach. If that's the case, please let me know so that I can take another approach which might not cause this error.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing - I'm refactoring some initial swift/core data work - and am trying to move the serialization code into the managed object model (as described in the alamofire documenation) and in this Wenderlich tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/87595/intermediate-alamofire-tutorial

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a better encapsulation - keep the core data model clean - and use another object that's composed of your object model class and also conforms to ResponseObjectSerializable...

Comment: @DanielD Even though the answer I gave, works for me, its still a hack or actually a _temporary_ workaround. I don't really like this approach, but once its fixed in the compiler I could just remove the `*.c` file and be done with it. It works in Objective-C, so its probably going to be fixed.

Anyway, I've been thinking about another approach, using two objects. One which conforms to the ResponseObjectSerializable protocol and the other a nice and clean Core Data model (like you've said). I would simply need to apply the properties of the first to the latter before saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm new to Swift I didn't realize that the `__T` prefixed string is actually a mangled Swift symbol. When passed to the `swift-demangle` tool, it translates to:

```
__TFC7Project3Foo3barSS ---> Project.Foo.bar.setter : Swift.String
```

Which apparently means that the setter method doesn't exist. According to [this](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2015/02/20/using-core-data-with-swift/) post, this is a bug in the compiler. `@NSManaged` properties are entirely dynamic, so this function does not exist for managed properties at all, but some part of the Swift compiler still generates code which uses it.

The same post describes that the missing function is not really needed anyway, so we could fool the compiler about its presence by adding a simple C file to the project:

```
void _TFC7Project3Foo3barSS() {}
```

After adding the file the project builds and runs fine, but it is a **hack**. So, this is a *workaround* until its actually fixed in the compiler.

It has been reported as a radar [here](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6421938515738624).